# Why does XRay Scan for jFrog Artifacts triggered from Jenkins returns a forbidden response?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I tried triggering the Xray Scan from Jenkins through the jFrog server as specified in their documentation.

The pipeline code used is as follows:

```
node {
        stage('XRAY Scan') { 
            def server = Artifactory.server('jFrogServer')    
            def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

            buildInfo.env.capture = true

            def scanConfig = [
                'buildName'      : buildInfo.name,
                'buildNumber'    : buildInfo.number,
                'failBuild'      : true
                ]    
            def scanResult = server.xrayScan(scanConfig)
            echo scanResult as String
        }
}
```

When this pipeline is executed, I get the following response in the console:

`Xray scan connection lost: Artifactory response: Forbidden, attempting to reconnect...`

Comment: What is the Xray version you are using?

Comment: What is the config for `jFrogServer` in jenkins? does the user used there hase appropriate permissions? Also what type of build you have? maven?

Answer (score 1):

I met this issue, all three times are the build info is missing or can't be found(by build name and build id), for example, the build info is not published to jfrog artifactory or the build name + id didn't match between jfrog and jenkins.